# Como reducir mi codigo en el controlador de laravel?

Tags: funciones, laravel-7

Estoy desarrollando mi primer proyecto medianamente grande en laravel, pero mi metodo store es demasiado extenso. Me gustaria poder enviar todo ese codigo a otro archivo y solo tener que llamar metodos desde mi controlador. De esa forma el codigo de mi controlador seria mucho mas legible, pero necesitaria pasar los datos del request y no se como pasar objetos como parametros a travez de un metodo.
Si tienen una idea mejor, no duden en dejarme saber.
Este es mi codigo:

```
        $usuario = auth()->user()->email;
        $monto = $request->monto;
        $id = $request->id;

        if ($id != null ) {
            
           $flores = Flores::where('id','=',$id)
                        ->Where(
                            function ($query) use ($usuario) {
                                $query->Where('usuario','=',$usuario);

                                for ($i=2; $i < 16; $i++) { 
                                    $query = $query->orWhere('usuario','!=' , $usuario);
                                }
                            }
                        ); */
        }
        else{  
            $flores = Flores::where('monto','=',$monto)
                            ->where(
                                function ($query) {
                                    $query->orWhere('usuario','!=',"usuario");
                                    for ($i=2; $i < 16; $i++) {
                                    $query = $query->whereNull('usuario'.$i)
                                                    ->orWhere('usuario'.$i,'!=',"usuario");
                                    }
                                }
                            );
        }
        $contador = $flores->count();
       // return $contador;


        $datos = $flores->get(); //Datos de la seleccion
       if ($contador <= 0) {
            $nuevaFlor = new Flores();
            $nuevaFlor->monto = $monto;
            $nuevaFlor->usuario = $usuario;
            $nuevaFlor->save();

            return redirect('Flores'); 
       }
        else{ //Si hay una flor con el monto deseado agregara al usuario en la posicion correspondiente
            foreach ($datos as $item){  // @foreach para las filas
                for ($i = 2; $i < 16; $i++){ // @for para las columnas
                    if ($item->{'usuario'.$i} == null) {
                        $flor_Actualizar = Flores::find($item->id);
                        $flor_Actualizar->{'usuario'.$i} = auth()->user()->email;
                        $flor_Actualizar->save();

                        if ($i == 15) {
                           return $this->division($actualizar);
                        }else{
                            return redirect('Flores');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Patrón repositorio

Comment: Te recomiendo trates de leer [ask], la pregunta me parece basadas en opiniones y eso motivaría su cierre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No hay problema en que una función sea larga siempre y cuando se enfoque en algo en concreto, cuando mezclas lógicas diferentes en una sola función ahí si es un problema.

En tu caso podrías crear una función en tu mismo controlador y llamarlos de acuerdo a las condiciones por ejemplo:

```
if ($id != null ) {
   $flores = $this->getFlowersFromUser($id, $usuario);
}

private function getFlowersFromUser($id, $usuario) {
   return Flores::where('id','=',$id)
                        ->Where(
                            function ($query) use ($usuario) {
                                $query->Where('usuario','=',$usuario);

                                for ($i=2; $i < 16; $i++) { 
                                    $query = $query->orWhere('usuario','!=' , $usuario);
                                }
                            }
                        ); 
}
```

Lo mismo harías con las demás consultas y solo llamarias el método cuando la condición se cumpla. Al ser metodos que solo se utilizan en la misma clase, defínelos como privados.

Si quieres tenerlos en un archivo apartado, podrías crear una carpeta exclusiva para ese controlador, en esa carpeta puedes crear 3 archivos, el controlador principal, el controlador "helper" donde colocaras funciones que no requieran utilizar la base de datos, y una que se enfoque en las funciones que requieran hacer consultas

Comment: Ojo aqui: `->Where` la w debe ser minúscula

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo!. Utilizare tu consejo